# Web Api returns multiple lists. How can i differ them and write to different arrays?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have web api that returns multiple lists (lets say `employersList`, `locationsList`...)

Currently i have this code:

```
  items = [];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getMember(){
    this.http.get('http://apirequest').toPromise().then(data =>{

      for(let key in data){
        if(data.hasOwnProperty(key))
        {
          this.items.push(data[key])
        }
      }
    })
  }
```

So i write them all to single array. How can i put the data into separate arrays?

Example of data i get from API request:

```
{
  "employersList": [
    {
      "id": 2319259,
      "employerName": "Jack Star",
    },
    {
      "id": 4337496,
      "employerName": "John Star",
    }
  ],
  "locationsList": []
}
```

Comment: What do you mean separate arrays? In the same object as you get from the API or you want to return multiple, separate arrays?

Comment: I mean, currently i am writing everything that is in json to array items[]. And i want to write it to arrays employersList[] and locationsList[]

Comment: Great, I think I understood, see my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need something like this

```
  items = { employersList: [], locationsList: [] };

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getMember(){
    this.http.get('http://apirequest').toPromise().then(data =>{
       const { employersList, locationsList } = data;
       this.items.employersList = employersList
       this.items.locationsList = locationsList
    })
  }
```